RPC error: [search], <ParamError: (code=1, message=`search_data` value
Getting the following error while performing the milvus vector search, I have created milvus collection and also pushed the data after creating the embeddings using google generative ai embedding model but not able to perform the similarity search.
def chat_collection(collection_name, query):
MILVUS_HOST = "host"
MILVUS_PORT = "port"
# Initialize result list
all_results = []

try:
    # Connect to Milvus
    connections.connect(host=MILVUS_HOST, port=MILVUS_PORT)
    print("Connected to Milvus")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error connecting to Milvus: {e}")
    return

# List of collections to search in
collections = [collection_name]
print("Collections to search:", collections)

for collection_name in collections:
    try:
        print("Processing collection:", collection_name)
       
        # Load the collection from Milvus
        collection = Collection(collection_name)
        collection.load()
        print("Collection loaded")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error loading collection {collection_name}: {e}")
        continue

    try:
        # Create embeddings for the query
        embeddings = GoogleGenerativeAIEmbeddings(model=os.getenv('EMBEDDING_MODEL'))
        vector = embeddings.embed_query(query)
        
    
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Unexpected error creating embeddings: {e}")
        continue

    try:
        # Define search parameters
        search_param = {
            "data": [vector],
            "consistency_level": "Session",
            "anns_field": "embedding",
            "param": {"metric_type": "COSINE", "params": {"radius": 0.7, "range_filter": 0.9}},
            "limit": 15,
            "output_fields": ['text', 'n_tokens', 'similarities'],
        }
        print("Search parameters defined:", search_param)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error defining search parameters: {e}")
        continue

    try:
        # Perform search on the collection
        results = collection.search(**search_param)
        print("Search completed")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error performing search: {e}")
        continue

    

I was tring to find the context based on the query provided from the specified milvus collection.

Do you have the host and port set correctly? Is there a firewall in the way? can you see Milvus with Attu or Command line tools? Can you post the complete error message? Thanks!
